# Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.1.0 или Version=2.3.2

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

Всем привет

При установке Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, **Version=2.3.2.0** ругается, что

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, **Version=1.4.1.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Но при установке Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, **Version=1.4.1.0**
ругается, что

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, **Version=2.3.2.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

В чем тут может быть дело?
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Версию дотнета надо угадать?

Comment: Версия .NET 4.7.2

Comment: Вы уверены, что эта версия поддерживется пакетом?

Comment: Установил .NET 4.6.2, но теперь ругается

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: почему именно .NET 4.6.2?

Comment: Какую вы рекомендуете?

Comment: .NET 6 например

Comment: У меня установлена VS 2019, а для .NET 6.0 требуется VS 2022.

Comment: 2019 поддерживает .NET 6, но вам конечно же никто не будет мешать поставить 2022, ну ок .NET 5 тоже подойдет

Comment: Спасибо, но что это даст?

Comment: Может и ничего не даст. В любом случае 4.x устарел уже давно. Скоро .NET 8 выйдет, а вы всё на 4.x сидите.

Comment: Разобрался. Переустановил Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, предварительно удалив упоминание о нем из app.config